# Check whether insertions were successful (MongoDB C# driver)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose "doc" is some document I want to insert into a MongoDB collection and "collection" is the  collection I am inserting the document into.

I have something like the following:

```
try
{
    WriteConcern wc = new WriteConcern();
    wc.W = 1;
    wc.Journal = true;

    WriteConcernResult wcResult = collection.Insert(doc, wc);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wcResult.ErrorMessage) || !wcResult.Ok)
    {
        return ErrorHandler(...); 
    }
    else
    {
        return SuccessFunction(...); 
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

Basically, if the insertion fails for any reason (other than hardware no longer working properly) I want to handle it (through the ErrorHandler function or the catch clause), while if it succeeds I want to call SuccessFunction.

My question: Is the above code sufficient for error checking purposes? In other words, will all failed insertions be caught, so that SuccessFunction is never called in those situations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't even need to do any checking. collection.Insert will throw an exception if the write was not successful when you are using any write concern other than unacknowledged.

If you want to know if an error occured, you need to catch a WriteConcernException.

Comment: Does this also work with multi-document operations? So if I insert or update multiple documents, but some of those inserts/updates fail, will that exception get thrown?

Comment: If you have a writeconcern specified, an exception will get thrown for the first error that occurs and no further documents will get inserted. If you have specified continueOnError = true, then you'll get 1 exception at the end.

Comment: Thanks! I just have one more question: does the WriteConcernException work with FindAndModifyResult as well, or just WriteConcernResult? If not, is there an equivalent for FindAndModifyResult or should I just check if the result is null?

Comment: FindAndModify doesn't support write concerns currently. If a findAndModify fails, you'll get a MongoCommandException. But you'll certainly want to check the results of a find and modify to see what exactly happened even upon success (i.e. was anything updated, was anything deleted, etc...)

Comment: @CraigWilson Do you what the reason was for insert to raise an exception but update, replace and delete to return results? MongoDB seems to return a result natively so it seems a little strange that this one is so different from the others.